# Gateway timeout in openshift pod

Tags: apache, openshift

I have deployed an apache server on openshift in a pod. It works fine in general. But after long period of inactivity, if i try it starts throwing  gateway timeout error. I had to delete the pod and create a new one and it works fine again.  Every time a, I have to kill the pod to get it working. Any idea if it is something from application or openshift route side?
There is nothing in apache logs though which could indicate where the issue is. It looks like the request is not even going to pod and timing out.

Comment: Did you look at [route-specific-annotations](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-specific-annotations_route-configuration) ?

Comment: yeah the real problem is if I try again after a long period of inactivity, the pod had to be killed before it works again. sorry I had to rephrase.